# What is difference between light harvesting complex , reaction centre and photosystem

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, photosynthesis

my book says light harvesting Complex are made up of hundred of pigment molecule bound to protein. Is photosystem has all the pigment (except one molecule of chlorophyll A )forming light harvesting complex also called and dinner this pigment help to make photosynthesis more efficient by observing different wavelength of light the single chlorophyll A molecule forms reaction centre.

These things are very confusing for me . I doesn't understand is light harvesting complex is present inside the photosystem or the photosystem is present inside the light harvesting complex.
Is reaction centre not a part of photosystem?